# NSolve not working unless I use Expand before in Mathematica 11

Tags: equation-solving, bugs, numerics, polynomials

I am using Mathematica 11, and I noticed this weird thing when using NSolve. Given the same equation in one variable, there are cases in which NSolve only finds the zeroes of the function if I first expand the expression. Here is a minimal working example:

```
eq = -z^8 (12 + 6 z + 6 z^6 + z^7);
NSolve[eq == 0, z]
NSolve[Expand[eq] == 0, z]
```

gives as output

```
{{}}

{{z -> -5.99949}, {z -> -0.940337 + 0.476287 I}, {z -> -0.940337 - 0.476287 I}, {z -> -0.065296 + 1.14115 I}, {z -> -0.065296 - 1.14115 I}, {z -> 0.}, {z -> 0.}, {z -> 0.}, {z -> 0.}, {z -> 0.}, {z -> 0.}, {z -> 0.}, {z -> 0.}, {z -> 1.00538 - 0.605903 I}, {z -> 1.00538 + 0.605903 I}}
```

This was surprising to me.
I tried using Mathematica 10.4 and the problem does not appear, and both NSolve have the same output and find the solutions.
Does anybody have an explanation on why this happens?

Comment: This is most odd. The same thing happens with eq = -z(1+z) but not with eq = z(1+z). This surely must be a bug.

Comment: With versions 11.1.0 and 10.4.1 `NSolve[eq == 0, z]` and `NSolve[Expand[eq] == 0, z]` produce the same output. But with version 11.0.1 the output is as in the question. So this is specific problem of version 11.0.

Comment: With Version 11.0.0.0 both outputs are the same.